# aws lambda version and alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml

I was working on aws lambda versioning and alias. I tried to create a new lambda version in already created function on template.yaml file. In Serverless function I tried to create new version and alias on already created function. But they didn't changing the lambda services. In the GUI mode(web portal) it is working. Please mention the code for creating the lambda version and alias. Please can anybody  help me?

Comment: Could you provide the template?

Comment: DeliforceSettingsBillingPut:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: Dev_deliforce_setting_billing_put
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      CodeUri: build/set_billing_put.zip
      Timeout: 300

Comment: put under the `Properties` a new one: `AutoPublishAlias: dev`

Comment: Thanks @TomasTulka.It is working for me.

Comment: @TomasTulka.  If any alternate method to create lambda versioning and  alias?If you that please give the code for that.

Answer (score 1):

To gain more low-level control avoid the simplicity of SAM and use direct the *CloudFormation* template model.

In this case are these elements interesting:

- `AWS::Lambda::Version`
- `AWS::Lambda::Alias`

The code looks like:

```
MyLambdaVersion:
  DeletionPolicy: Retain
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Version
  Properties:
    FunctionName:
      Ref: MyLambda

MyLambdaAlias:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
  Properties:
    FunctionVersion:
      Fn::GetAtt:
      - MyLambdaVersion
      - Version
    FunctionName:
      Ref: MyLambda
    Name: prod
```

Then, you can create the *CodeDeploy* for auto-deploying the new lambda version:

```
MyLambdaAlias:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
  UpdatePolicy:
    CodeDeployLambdaAliasUpdate:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: ServerlessDeploymentApplication
      DeploymentGroupName:
        Ref: MyLambdaDeploymentGroup
  ...

ServerlessDeploymentApplication:
  Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::Application
  Properties:
    ComputePlatform: Lambda             

MyLambdaDeploymentGroup:
  Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
  Properties:
    ApplicationName:
      Ref: ServerlessDeploymentApplication
    AutoRollbackConfiguration:
      Enabled: true
      Events:
      - DEPLOYMENT_FAILURE
      - DEPLOYMENT_STOP_ON_ALARM
      - DEPLOYMENT_STOP_ON_REQUEST
    ServiceRoleArn:
      Fn::GetAtt:
      - CodeDeployServiceRole
      - Arn
    DeploymentConfigName:
      Fn::Sub:
      - CodeDeployDefault.Lambda${ConfigName}
      - ConfigName: AllAtOnce
    DeploymentStyle:
      DeploymentType: BLUE_GREEN
      DeploymentOption: WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL
```

Please see the documentation for more info:

https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/cloudformation/
https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/codedeploy/

Comment: @Thomas Tulka,Thanks you for replied my question.

Comment: AWS::Lambda::Version and AWS::Lambda::Alias.I wrote in template.yml file after the resources.I have a doubt where I write the code for CodeDeploy for auto-deploying the new lambda version.same template.yml file or other files

Comment: I have the one lambda function.Function name is hello_lambda.With your help I will created one versioning and alias.I need to give more than one versioning and alias.I gave AutoPublishAlias: dev and AutoPublishAlias: Test.But it taking "Test" alias only.So can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the first sentence of my previous answer, my example uses CloudFormation instead SAM. But SAM consumes CloudFormation resources natively, so theoretically you can use the same SAM template to create CodeDeploy resources as well. But you CANNOT combinate `AutoPublishAlias` and `AWS::Lambda::Alias`.

With SAM `AutoPublishAlias` you can't have more then one alias in a stack. It means, you have to use a) more stacks b) `AWS::Lambda::Alias` resources.

The Lambda from my example could look like:

```
MyLambda:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    FunctionName: my-lambda
    Runtime: nodejs6.10
    Handler: index.handler
    MemorySize: 1024
    Timeout: 120
    Role: !GetAtt MyLambdaRole.Arn
    Code:
      ZipFile: >
        exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
            console.log("Hello World!")
        }
```

This is all **CloudFormation** stuff.

Comment: I 'll tried  first approach.That time I got a error like this" functionname my-lambda is already exist in the Dev Stack."And I changed the  function name.That time it's updated.without changing the function name how we can update the version and alias

Comment: I don't understand the problem, everything must be consistent within the stack. Please clean up the resources first.

Comment: ,I 'll give exact requirement.I have one function name is My-lambda.The same above code is I used.I don't how to create versioning and alias in template.yaml file.Below I give some example.Function name= My-lambda.Version is 1.And Alias is Dev.After that I need version is 2.And alias is Test.Actually I want like this.How I create like this.Please mention the code

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than 1 alias, but managing the additional ones will require a custom resource. Check out: [how-to-use-sam-deploy-to-get-a-lambda-with-autopublishalias-and-additional-alises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63821300/how-to-use-sam-deploy-to-get-a-lambda-with-autopublishalias-and-additional-alis)